# chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval to inspect element in Iframe (iframe without Iframe URL)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In my extension I am highlighting the node that I have XPATH for. 
the code below works if I have Iframe with URL hello.com

```js
var script = "var nodes = document.evaluate(\"" + issue.xpath + "\", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);" +
                "var node = nodes.iterateNext();" +
                "if(node){" +
                "inspect(node);" +
                "}"
            chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(script, {
                frameURL:
            });
```

But it does not work for the Iframw WITH OUT url

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Main Page</h2>
    <iframe id="Iframe" title="my Iframe">
        <html>

        <head>
        </head>

        <body>
            <h2>Iframe</h2>

        </body>

        </html>
    </iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

What would be the URL in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Chromium source code ([ExtensionServer.js](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/extensions/ExtensionServer.js?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=924)) shows that inspectedWindow.eval() can't do that:

> ```
> var frame = options.frameURL ? resolveURLToFrame(options.frameURL) : WebInspector.targetManager.mainTarget().resourceTreeModel.mainFrame;
> if (!frame) {
>     if (options.frameURL)
>         console.warn("evaluate: there is no frame with URL " + options.frameURL);
>     else
>         console.warn("evaluate: the main frame is not yet available");
>     return this._status.E_NOTFOUND(options.frameURL || "<top>");
> }
> ```

Submit a feature request on [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org).

I'm not aware of a workaround, but have a look at advanced devtools extensions, e.g. [famous](https://github.com/simple10/famous-inspector) and others.

Comment: logged defect on chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=637304&can=2&q=inspectedWindow&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified#